# How to send additional parameters using Upload.upload in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload file using angular js

```
var requestData = {
      url: "/file_upload",
      data: {"name":"jack", file:file},
    };

Upload.upload(requestData);
```

This is what my controller have.

```
app.post("/file_upload", function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body.name);
   res.send("uploading...");
});
```

This is what my route have.
Here it is printing 'undefined' instead of name.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send more parameters in `data` field.

This is how I'm using upload function :

```
Upload.upload({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    file: file,
    data: {name:'Hello!'} // Here you can send JSON parameters
});
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

This is how I'm receiving my file on Node.js side

**Multer middleware function**

```
var uploader = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, next) {
            next(null, '/path/to/final/file');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, next) {
            next(null, 'finalFileName.csv');
        }
    }),
    limits: {
        fieldNameSize: 100,
        fileSize: 20000000,
        files: 1,
        fields: 5
    }
}).single('file');
```

**My route**

```
server.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
    uploader(req, res, function (err) { // call uploader middleware
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else if (req.file) {
            console.log(req.file);
            console.log(req.body.name); // I can use parameters
            res.status(200).json('OK!').end();
        }
        else {
            res.status(424).json('Error !').end();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What are you using to receive the file or the server side ?

Comment: node js (express) and package is multer ..you can see it on my question

Comment: Sure, but are you using "multer" module or something like this ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Upload.upload({
    url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            details: {name: jack},
            files: files
        }
}).then(function (success) {
    console.log(success);
});
```